# Creating time-based ('After', 'Before') relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

My goal is to create a relationship between events ('NEXT', 'PREV'). I have a set of data with two types of nodes, and one relationship. The `(:Person)` is `-[:AT]->` an `(:Event)`. In fact, they are often at multiple events (think football games). Each `(:Event)` has a `.datenum` property which is the number of days since whenever, doesn't matter.

I'd like to, for each person, create a relationship that links their events together based on this `:Event.datenum` using the relationship `-[:NEXT]->`. Thus, I'd like to see `(:Event)-[:NEXT]->(:Event)`. I am having trouble creating the relationship because I can't think of a way to identify, for each person, their first (minimum `.datenum`) event. I need some sort of group by clause to establish an ordering of the `.datenums` to direct the relationships.

I'm pretty new to Cypher so figure I must be missing something (or still thinking in RDBMS). Any thoughts? Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want to create an ordering between a specific person's attendance at an event then you need to introduce the concept of their attendance e.g.

```
(:Person)-[:ATTENDED]->(:Attendance)-[:EVENT]->(:Event)
```

Otherwise if you just have the 'AT' relationship then there isn't a way to order those as you can't create a relationship between relationships.

So assuming you have the concept of attendance, you could then order those attendances like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ATTENDED]->(attendance)
WITH p, attendance
ORDER BY p.name, attendance.timestamp
WITH p, COLLECT(attendance) AS attendances

FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, length(attendances)-2) | 
  FOREACH(si in [attendances[i]] | 
    FOREACH(si2 in [attendances[i+1]] | 
      MERGE (si)-[:NEXT]->(si2))))
```

Hope that makes sense. Let me know if not.